# How to fetch data from google book api using python

Tags: python, google-api

I am working on book recommendation system, so with ml i have got the recommendation which is stored is list book_list, so using google book api i have tried to fetch the book cover of the listed item in the book_list

```
but show KeyError: 'imageLinks'
```

**KeyError: 'imageLinks'**

here is app.py, here the user will enter the book name in the form and will get recommendation after getting the recommedation i have tried to fetch the image links

```
@app.route('/search',methods=['GET','POST'])
def search():
    choice = request.args.get('search')
    # removing all the characters except alphabets and numbers.
    # passing the choice to the recommend() function
    # passing the choice to the recommend() function
    books = recommend(choice)
    image=get_image(books)
    # if rocommendation is a string and not list then it is else part of the
    # recommend() function.
    if type(books) == type('string'):
        return render_template('read.html', book=books,image=image)
    else:
        return render_template('read.html', book=books,image=image)
```

here is the code where i have tried to fetch the image links

```
def get_image(books):
    img=[]
    for i in range(len(books)):
        response=requests.get(url + books[i])
        obj=json.loads(response.text)
        w=obj['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail']
        img.append(w)
    return img
```

this is url , i have placed before running the flask app

```
url='https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='
 
app=Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: You need to print the JSON response you're getting.  The error says that the `volumeInfo` object does not contain an `imageLinks` key.

Comment: Do you realize that both branches of your `if` statement are identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageLinks in volumeInfo isn't available for every book

for example

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=test

the '0' book "Software-Test für Embedded Systems" doesn't contain imageLinks

you need to try/catch that case or look beforehand if it exists

```
for...
   ...
   try:
    w=obj['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail']
    img.append(w)
  except:
    print("imgageLinks not found")
return img
...
```

Comment: Well I tried to do that but it's not working ,can u explain me with a example pls